# FileGDB not found when compiling GDAL 2.1.1, 2.1.4, 2.2.1

Tags: compiler-errors, gdal

I am attempting to compile GDAL with FileGDB support. The following two scripts are run, the first to get ESRI FileGDB and the second to compile GDAL with the `with-fgdb` support flag set:

```
mkdir -p /provisioning/filegdb && \
curl -# -o filegdb_api_${FILEGDB_VERSION}-64.tar.gz ${FGDB_SOURCE} && \
tar -zxvf filegdb_api_${FILEGDB_VERSION}-64.tar.gz && \
cp -r FileGDB_API-64/lib/* /usr/local/lib && \
cp -r FileGDB_API-64/include/* /usr/local/include && \
ldconfig -v

# Compile GDAL with FileGDB support for Fiona/Geopandas Python packages
mkdir -p /provisioning/gdal && \
cd /provisioning/gdal && \
curl -# -o gdal-2.2.1.tar.gz http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/2.2.1/gdal-2.2.1.tar.gz && \
tar -zxvf gdal-2.2.1.tar.gz && \
cd /provisioning/gdal/gdal-2.2.1 && \
./configure --prefix=/usr/ --with-python --with-fgdb && \
make -j$(python -c 'import multiprocessing; 
print(multiprocessing.cpu_count())')
```

This results in the following error:

```
configure: error: FileGDBAPI not found.
```

I see this issue as having last been discussed on the OSGeo mailing list back in ’12 (http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2012-March/032164.html).

I have attempted this with GDAL versions 2.1.1, 2.1.4, and 2.2.1.

OS is based on this Docker image: `python:3.6-stretch`.

Any guidance as to how to circumvent this issue would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--with fgdb` should point to the folder of the API. See https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FileGDB and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292506/how-do-i-install-esri-file-gdb-api-in-ubuntu-16-04-so-qgis-2-8-can-see-it for an example.

Note that you need the gcc51 variant of the ESRI FileGDB API for Ubuntu 16.04 and newer, and for Debian stretch (which comes with gcc 6.3.0).